# Need help formatting CoffeeScript using the plugin in Visual Studios 2012

Tags: coffeescript

What's the exact CofeeScript to produce the following JavaScript:

```
var AddArtist= function() {
      var addDiv, artistVal;
      addDiv = $("#artistname");
      artistVal = $("#artistinput").val();
      $(" <div id=\"artistname2\"><label>" + artistVal + "</label> /div>").appendTo(addDiv);
      return false;
    };
```

I tried using http://js2coffee.org/ to convert this to Cofee

which produces:

```
AddArtist = ->
  addDiv = undefined
  artistVal = undefined
  addDiv = $("#artistname")
  artistVal = $("#artistinput").val()
  $(" <div id=\"artistname2\"><label>" + artistVal + "</label> /div>").appendTo addDiv
  false
```

When I paste this into Visual Studios which uses the CofeeScript plugin the ouput is:

```
(function() {
  var AddArtist;

  AddArtist = function() {
    var addDiv, artistVal;
    addDiv = $("#artistname");
    artistVal = $("#artistinput").val();
    $(" <div id=\"artistname2\"><label>" + artistVal + "</label> /div>").appendTo(addDiv);
    return false;
  };

}).call(this);
```

So the CoffeeScript plugin is wrapping the script into another function so the The AddArtist variable never leaves the scope of the inner function.

Which results in a "Uncaught reference error AddArtist" on my web page.

The question is using the Visual Studios plugin, what the exact cofee script to produce the below JavaScript which works

```
var AddArtist= function() {
      var addDiv, artistVal;
      addDiv = $("#artistname");
      artistVal = $("#artistinput").val();
      $(" <div id=\"artistname2\"><label>" + artistVal + "</label> /div>").appendTo(addDiv);
      return false;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

CoffeeScript will wrap the generated JavaScript in a function wrapper to keep things from [accidentally leaking into the global scope](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical-scope) unless you [compile with `--bare`](http://coffeescript.org/#usage):

> `-b, --bare`
>   Compile the JavaScript without the top-level function safety wrapper.

If you want `AddArtist` to be in the global scope the you have to explicitly put it there:

```
@AddArtist = ->
  addDiv = $("#artistname")
  artistVal = $("#artistinput").val()
  $("<div id='artistname2'><label>#{artistVal}</label></div>").appendTo addDiv
  false
```

or:

```
window.AddArtist = -> ...
```

if you're only worrying about a browser environment. I've also cleaned up some of the other things js2coffee did to your code.

js2coffee has some other bugs so I'd recommend that you either leave your working JavaScript as JavaScript or learn CoffeeScript and do the conversion manually. CoffeeScript ends up as JavaScript anyway so there's no need to convert working code. And if you do the conversion manually, you'll end up understanding CoffeeScript better and you'll have more idiomatic CoffeeScript code as you'll be translating the intent and function rather than just the tokens.